# Changing DateComponents to show 2 decimal places?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have been trying for a while to change my label to 2 decimal places from my DateComponents. While I have found some solutions online, they don't seem to work for when you are calculating a difference in time.

```
let userCalendar = Calendar.current
let date = Date()
let components = userCalendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .month, .year, .day, .second], from: date)
let currentDate = userCalendar.date(from: components)!


let timeDifference = userCalendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: currentDate, to: dateStored as! Date)
label.text = "\(timeDifference.day!): \(timeDifference.hour!): \(timeDifference.minute!): \(timeDifference.second!)"
```

The code above produces a label that shows 0:0:0:0 by default but I want it to show 00:00:00:00 by default. So for 9 seconds it shows 0:0:0:9 but it should show 00:00:00:09.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: format your components like `String(format: "%02d", timeDifference.day!)`

Comment: Are you sure about that format since it is very hard to read? I is unusual to use : between day and hour, normally space is used instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Answer is

```
String(format: "%02d", timeDifference.day!)
```

or If you want use this many times in your project, write a extension for it.You can add any number of zeroes you want.

```
extension Int {
    func addLeadingZero(_ leadingZeroCount:Int = 2)->String {
        return String(format: "%0\(leadingZeroCount)d", self)
    }
}

print((timeDifference.day!).addLeadingZero()) //09
print((timeDifference.day!).addLeadingZero(3)) //009
```

Comment: I used the simple method! Works great! I was trying to do this before but was placing it wrongly in my code. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This answer generate a different output but I think it is easier to read and it uses the built in DateComponentsFormatter

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.day, .hour, .minute, .second]
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
```

If the `timeDifference` is 9 seconds

```
formatter.string(from: timeDifference)
```

would output

> 0d 00:00:09

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern to generate 0-prefixed component

```
String(format: "%02d", timeDifference.day!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
extension Int {
    func getFirst2Digit()->String {
        let numberAsString = String(number)
        let subString = numberAsString.substringToIndex(numberAsString.startIndex.advancedBy(2))
        return numberAsString
    }
}
```

Then just use this

```
label.text = "\(timeDifference.day!.getFirst2Digit()): \(timeDifference.hour!.getFirst2Digit()): \(timeDifference.minute!.getFirst2Digit()): \(timeDifference.second!.getFirst2Digit())"
```